# Sequelise creates weird query

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 3 tables `city, car, images`

I need to get cars of cities for `city/parent_id = 21` and images of the cars as well. (using a where clause to filter images on bases of sort_number)

My raw query is this:

```
SELECT
    `car`.`car_id`,
    `car`.`chassis_no`,
    `images`.`car_image_id` AS `images.car_image_id`,
    `images`.`directory` AS `images.directory`,
    `images`.`file_name` AS `images.file_name`
FROM `car` AS `car`
INNER JOIN `city` AS `city` ON
        `car`.`parent_id` = `city`.`id`
        AND `city`.`parent_id` = 21
INNER JOIN `images` AS `images` ON
    `car`.`car_id` = `images`.`car_id`
    AND `images`.`sort_number` = 1
limit 0, 5;
```

and the Sequelise generated query is this:

```
explain SELECT
    `car` .*,
    `images`.`car_image_id` AS `images.car_image_id`,
    `images`.`directory` AS `images.directory`,
    `images`.`file_name` AS `images.file_name`
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        `car`.`car_id`,
        `car`.`chassis_no`
    FROM
        `car` AS `car`
    INNER JOIN `city` AS `city` ON
        `car`.`parent_id` = `city`.`id`
        AND `city`.`parent_id` = 21
    WHERE
        (
        SELECT
            `car_id`
        FROM
            `images` AS `images`
        WHERE
            (`images`.`sort_number` = 1
            AND `images`.`car_id` = `car`.`car_id`)
        LIMIT 1 ) IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 0,
    5) AS `car`
INNER JOIN `images` AS `images` ON
    `car`.`car_id` = `images`.`car_id`
    AND `images`.`sort_number` = 1;
```

Doing explain shows the sequelise query is not very efficient and it does looks weird to me, instead of plane joins. The result of the both queries are same though.

There are my relations:

```
//Relations
city.hasMany(car, { foreignKey: 'parent_id', sourceKey: 'id' })
car.belongsTo(city, {
  foreignKey: 'parent_id',
  sourceKey: 'id'
})

car.hasMany(image, { foreignKey: 'car_id', sourceKey: 'car_id' })
image.belongsTo(car, { foreignKey: 'car_id', sourceKey: 'car_id' })
```

The query code as follows:

```
return this.findAll({
      attributes: ['car_id', 'car_model'],
      include: [
        {
          model: db.city,
          required: true,
          attributes: [],
          where: { parent_id: 21 }
        },
        {
          model: db.image,
          required: true,
          attributes: ['image_id', 'file_name'],
          where: { sort_number: 1 }
        }
      ],
      offset: 0,
      limit: 5
    })
```

Is there any way to make it like the raw query join I have above? What am I missing?
Is Sequelise limmited in generating better queries?
Should I use raw query function to write my joins myself it can't be helped?

Please guide, I'm new to sequelise. sorry for long post.